# How to turn individual points into a kernel density map?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, geopandas

I am trying to recreate in Python a map I made in Tableau. I'm pretty sure it's called a kernel density map (just "density" map in Tableau). Each point is just a single point and doesn't correspond with any kind of value.

[image: Tableau Map]

I have plotted my points on a map, but am unable to figure out how to give them the contour appearance in the Tableau map. I see some examples that include np.meshgrid or matplotlib's contourf function, but I'm unable to apply it to my data because I don't have a Z coordinate (from what I can tell). Below is what I have currently:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta, date
import matplotlib
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Point, mapping


# import data
df = pd.read_csv('./Data/complete.csv', on_bad_lines='skip') # csv had some bad data, had to skip

# drop unneccessary columns
df = df[['datetime', 'latitude', 'longitude']]

# convert 'datetime' to YYYY-MM-DD
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], dayfirst=True)

# clean the data
# remove values that contain '/' and 'q'
df = df.drop(df[df.latitude.str.contains(r'[/q]')].index)

# convert lat/long to float
df['latitude'] = df.latitude.astype('float')
df['longitude'] = df.longitude.astype('float')

# create GDF from lat/long
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.longitude, df.latitude)).set_crs('EPSG:4326')


# import shapefile
us_map = gpd.read_file(r'./Data/USA_States_(Generalized)/USA_States_Generalized.shp')

#remove AK and HI
us_map = us_map[~us_map['STATE_NAME'].isin(['Alaska', 'Hawaii'])]


# plotting only 2012 sightings
sightings2012 = df[(df['datetime'] > '12/31/2011') & (df['datetime'] < '01/01/2013')]

# create GDF for 2012 sightings
gdf2012 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(sightings2012, 
                           geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(sightings2012.longitude, 
                                                       sightings2012.latitude)).set_crs('EPSG:4326')

# clip the sightings data
us_sightings_2012 = gpd.clip(gdf2012, us_map)


cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('plasma')

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
us_map.plot(ax=ax)
us_sightings_2012.plot(ax=ax, cmap=cmap)

plt.show()
```

And here is my output:

[image: Output image]

Comment: `... (just "density" map in Tableau). Each point is just a single point and doesn't correspond with any kind of value`. What you explained is a `heatmap` here the reference https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/maps_howto_heatmap.htm

Comment: @swatchai Correct, but I want to know how to create it in Python as I know how to create it in Tableau.

Comment: Hexbin demo https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/hexbin_demo.html